# How do I set the text of an element within a Zend_Form decorator

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-decorators

I am trying to set the text inside the lengend tag within the following code:

```
    $element->setDecorators(array(
        'ViewHelper',
        'Description',
        'Errors',
        array(array('legend' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'legend', 'placement' => 'prepend')),
        array(array('fieldset' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'fieldset')),
    ));
```

The following is generated:

```
    <fieldset>
    <legend></legend>
    </fieldset>
```

and I would like:

```
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Blah</legend>
    </fieldset>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

**Update:**

Using Regis's answer, I implemented this like so:

```
    $decorator = new Zend_Form_Decorator_Fieldset();
    $decorator->setLegend("legend");

    $element->setDecorators(array(
        'ViewHelper',
        'Description',
        'Errors',
        array($decorator),
        array(array('div' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div')),
    ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try in this different way:

```
$decorator = new Zend_Form_Decorator_Fieldset();
$decorator->setLegend("legend");        
$element->addDecorators(array($decorator));
```